# Is it possible to set a favicon to a pdf file in my cakephp website

Tags: cakephp-2.0

The pdf links in my cakephp website doesn't display the favicon,is it possible to get my favicon to display on the pdf page?Right now I use the following line in my default.ctp to display favicon on my website but it doesnt work with pdf files

```
 echo $this->Html->meta('icon',$this->Html->url('/favicon.ico'));
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Put the favicon file in the root directory instead of a subdirectory.  I had the same issue until I moved it out of my images directory.  Test with a different browser/computer or clear your cache to refresh the favicon.